# Match sub-strings that start with a character

Tags: php, regex

I want to match parts of a string that start with a certain character (asterisk):

`abc*DEFxyz`  => `*DEF`

`abc*DE*Fxyz` => `*DE`, `*F`

Tried `preg_match_all('/[$\*A-Z]+/', $string, $matches);` But it doesn't seem to work. I get `*DE*F` on the 2nd example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex  to this :
`\*[A-Z]+`

http://regexr.com?34itc

Your regex here : `[$\*A-Z]+`  means a string containing `*` and A-Z characters, not mentioning anything about start.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^[^*]*\*
```

which says "from the start of the line, skip over all non-asterisk characters and stop at the first"

Extending this:

```
s/^[^*]*\*(.*)/
```

Will return the remainder of the string after the asterisk. To include the asterisk, adjust like this

```
s/^[^*]*(\*.*)/
```

Here's a great tool for checking your regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Hope this helps